# Perl, Net::SSH2, how to read a whole data from ssh?

Tags: perl, ssh, libssh2

I need to read program output using Net::SSH2. My problem is some of that data hided under the bottom of program output. In ssh-mode I need to enter "Return" on my keyboard to look up next. This is awkward for using in a perl-script =). 
I know that Net::OpenSSH does it well, but I really need to use Net::SSH2. Does anybody know, how can I get it?
Thnx!

UPD: Some code below

```
my $ch = $ssh2->channel();

$ch->blocking(0);
$ch->shell();

print $ch "dir\n";
print $_ while <$ch>;
```

In this code I print output of command with "--More--" prompt of the terminal at the bottom.
Simple Net::OpenSSH "capture" method returns a whole data at the same time:

```
my @dirlist = $ssh->capture('dir');
```

Is it possible to do same thing using Net::SSH2?

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Yes, sorry, see UPD in the topic.

Comment: Net::SSH2 doesn't appear to have the best documentation. The channel object does have pty() function which gives you a terminal object. You can try changing the terminal size of that object.

Comment: No, it's not working for me. I think, it should be another connection mode or something like this... Can Net::SSH2 work exactly like Net::OpenSSH?

Comment: There is [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::SSH::Any) that provides a subset of Net::OpenSSH API and can run on top of Net::SSH2.